# .htaccess how to redirect unknown folder name to it's parent but ignoring sub-folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have to make a redirect to the parent (index) directory but maintaining the 2nd sub-folder available. Also the first sub-folder has many unknown random names, like:

```
domain.com/puzzles/index/random-id15345/v01/
domain.com/puzzles/index/random-id26654/v02/
domain.com/puzzles/index/random-id36544/v03/
```

Etc, people should be able to access those URLs but not to the parent "random-ids" directories, which are unknown strings. If one attempts to enter by deleting the "v01/" part of the url like so:

```
domain.com/puzzles/index/random-id36544/
```

it should redirect them to the index:

```
domain.com/puzzles/index/
```

Thanks.

Comment: So `domain.com/puzzles/index/random-id15345/v01/` already work for you and you just a rule to handle `domain.com/puzzles/index/random-id15345/` etc?

Comment: Yes everything works i just don't want smartismarty-pants snooping where they shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(puzzles/index/)[^/?]+/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks I'll test it when i get home and accept it or let you know if something goes wrong.

Comment: Yes! It works but it caused pagination of index to stop working, urls like: puzzles/index/?page=2 , and any page number does nothing now when clicked. Is there any way to not affect the pagination parameters?

Comment: Seem to be the same, pagination not working the rest fine.

Comment: Thanks so much! Pagination works yet redirect happens as needed and subfolders work too.